# Join Not Displaying Selected Items - Using Svelte

Tags: html, checkbox, svelte, svelte-3

What this code does: If no flavours are selected, "Please select at least one flavour" & "You ordered and undefined is displayed". Then if a flavour is selected, nothing is displayed.

What I'm trying to do: If no flavours are selected, "Please select at least one flavour" is displayed. Then only if something is selected, I want to display "You ordered (then list whatever they ordered)" ie: You ordered Mint choc chip, cookies and cream".

I'm confused because I thought that `${flavours.slice(0, -1).join(', ')};`  & `You ordered {join(flavours)}` would list the flavours selected. This is the code that I'm playing around with. (credit: Svelte example from Svelte website)

```
 <script>
        let scoops = 1;
        let flavours = ['Mint choc chip'];

        let menu = [
            'Cookies and cream',
            'Mint choc chip',
            'Raspberry ripple'
        ];

        function join(flavours) {
            if (flavours.length === 1) return flavours[0];
            return `${flavours.slice(0, -1).join(', ')};
        }
    </script>

    <h2>Flavours</h2>

    {#each menu as flavour}
        <label>
            <input type=checkbox bind:group={flavours} value={flavour}>
            {flavour}
        </label>
    {/each}

    {#if flavours.length === 0}
        <p>Please select at least one flavour</p>
        <p>
            You ordered {join(flavours)}
        </p>
    {/if}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a few mistakes...

You're missing a quote (but that's a syntax error, I guess you would have noticed if you have this in your original code because it wouldn't work at all):

```js
return `${flavours.slice(0, -1).join(', ')};

// fixed:
return `${flavours.slice(0, -1).join(', ')}`;

// you don't need the quotes here, anyway:
return flavours.slice(0, -1).join(', ');
```

You're also missing a `else`, that's why your code display nothing when some values are selected:

```html
    {#if flavours.length === 0}
        <p>Please select at least one flavour</p>

    {:else} <-- HERE -->

        <p>
            You ordered {join(flavours)}
        </p>
    {/if}
```

And, finally, why the `slice`? It drops the last value, is that really what you want?

```js
// fixed
return flavours.join(', ');
```

Comment: No, the slice was in the example I took from Svelte's website, I forgot to change it when I put my code here, same thing with the quote. Thanks for the help, it solved my problem. @rixo